# Android beacon addMonitorNotifier

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

beacon manager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier()
in this method, there are two methods and both are not running .... it is a small app of beacon I want to show the alert .... and that alert in my method in if condition ... but it is not running I did debugger but it is not working

```
import java.util.Collection;

public class WebViewScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

    public  static final String TAG="MainActivity";
    private  Button startbtn,stopbtn;
    private BeaconManager beaconManager=null;
    private  static final String ALTBEACON_LAYOUT="m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25";
    private Region beaconRegion=null;

    private void ShowAlert(final String title, final String message){
        runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebViewScreen.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle(title);
                alertDialog.setMessage(message);
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }));
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        Log.d(TAG,"on create called");
        startbtn=findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopbtn=findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1234);

        beaconManager=BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(ALTBEACON_LAYOUT));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startBiconMonitoring();
            }
        });
        stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopBiconMonitoring();

            }
        });

    }
    private boolean entryMessageRaised=false;
    private boolean exitMessageRaised=false;
    private boolean rangingMessageRaised=false;

    private void stopBiconMonitoring() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Stop Beacon Monitering");
        try {

            beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBiconMonitoring() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Start Beacon Monitering");
        try {
          beaconRegion = new Region("My Bicons",Identifier.parse("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"),Identifier.parse("4"),Identifier.parse("200"));
          beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
          beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void findID() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                if (!entryMessageRaised){
                    showAlert("didEnterRegion","Entering Region"+region.getUniqueId()+"Beacon Detected UUID/Major/Minor:"+region.getId1()+"/"+region.getId2()+"/"+region.getId3());
                    entryMessageRaised=true;
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"somrething go wrong");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                if (!exitMessageRaised){
                    showAlert("didExitRegion","Exiting Region"+region.getUniqueId()+"Beacon Detected UUID/Major/Minor:"+region.getId1()+"/"+region.getId2()+"/"+region.getId3());
                    exitMessageRaised=true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

            }
        });
       beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
           @Override
           public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
               if (rangingMessageRaised && collection != null && !collection.isEmpty()){
                   for (Beacon beacon:collection){
                       showAlert("didExitRegion","Ranging Region"+region.getUniqueId()+"Beacon Detected UUID/Major/Minor:"+beacon.getId1()+"/"+beacon.getId2()+"/"+beacon.getId3());
                   }
                   rangingMessageRaised=true;
               }
           }
       });
    }



}
```

I want to show the alert if the device will found bacon

Comment: Does onBeaconServiceConnect get called?  Are you sure the beacon you are looking for is an ALTBEACON?  If it is iBeacon, you need to add a different parser.

Comment: please help i am stuck here

Comment: I can't help you if you won't clarify your question as I have requested.

Comment: i want to scan the beacon ..... but when i am scanning .... the all bluetooth devices ar coming .. i want onlu ibeacon

Comment: no ist not depend that there is biacon is fixed it can be any kind of beacon